# How to change text font, size and format on selected text in NativeScript?

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am working on an application where a user can type in textView and change font size, font and font format (bold,italic,underline) for selected text. I am unable to find any rich Text Editor in Nativescript.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there aren't any NativeScript rich text editor plugins (as far as I know). You probably could create something yourself with a [`TextView`](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html#textview) and use buttons to change the font size/color/format (bold, italic, underline) but I don't you would be able to change only portions of the text. It would probably be all the text, or nothing, for formatting which may defeat the purpose.

Another possible idea is to use a [`WebView`](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html#textview) and then use an existing HTML rich text editor like [`QuillJs`](https://quilljs.com/) inside of it but not sure how well this would work.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, i checked and building something from scratch will take a long time. However i did come across this, checking it on how i can integrate it in my project. https://github.com/finalsite/nativescript-plugins/tree/master/packages/rich-text-editor

Comment: Ok yeah that uses a `WebView` like I mentioned in my second point. That's definitely a great starting point as opposed to starting something from scratch.